# Localstack - server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-emr, localstack

Using Localstack for creating aws cluster and its not able to download from github , as i am running inside office proxy tried also to give resource bundle of ca cert using but still not able to download github repo , do i need some addtional settings in localstack for downloading repos from github

```
ERROR: '['pip', 'install', 'git+https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs.git#egg=aws-glue-libs']': exit code 1; output: b"Collecting aws-glue-libs\n  Cloning https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs.git to /tmp/pip-install-9h46xhw4/aws-glue-libs_9df5b9cae1e84b908608601337548c8d\n  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs.git /tmp/pip-install-9h46xhw4/aws-glue-libs_9df5b9cae1e84b908608601337548c8d\n  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none\n  error: subprocess-exited-with-error\n  \n  \xc3\x97 git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs.git /tmp/pip-install-9h46xhw4/aws-glue-libs_9df5b9cae1e84b908608601337548c8d did not run successfully.\n  \xe2\x94\x82 exit code: 128\n  \xe2\x95\xb0\xe2\x94\x80> See above for output.\n  \n  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.\nerror: subprocess-exited-with-error\n\n\xc3\x97 git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs.git /tmp/pip-install-9h46xhw4/aws-glue-libs_9df5b9cae1e84b908608601337548c8d did not run successfully.\n\xe2\x94\x82 exit code: 128\n\xe2\x95\xb0\xe2\x94\x80> See above for output.\n\nnote: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.\n\n[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1\n[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip\n"
```